# Make java applications behave normally with reguard to the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, java, taskbar

I have a java application that is launched from a batch file as follows:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0_16
SET JAVA_EXE="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
%JAVA_EXE% -Xmx128m -jar ASHV.jar
```

I can create a shortcut to the batch file, but the shortcut can't be pinned to the Windows 7 taskbar.  I found that by specifying the shortcut path as follows I could pin the shortcut:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C C:\oracle\ashv-3.4-bin\run.bat
```

The problem is that now the shortcut and the java application both get their own icons on the taskbar.  What I would like is for there to be one button on the taskbar that both lauches the application and is used to switch to the application (as it is for most applications).

Comment: http://www.ucware.com/jexec/

Comment: http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html

Comment: I'd rather not spend $79 or $69 (respectively) to make this work.  I don't understand what the third link is for.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried two free applications similar to these, Launch4j and JSmooth.  Both were able to create an executable with an icon, but when launched they each created a new separate taskbar icon using the java logo.  Perhaps it is a limitation of this application.